# quick question on automorphisms of fields

Tags: field-theory

Is it true that a field automorphism must fix the elements of any proper subfield?
Ie, since $\mathbb{Q}\subset\mathbb{R}$, all automorphisms from R to itself must preserve the map from $I:\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Q}$?

note: I know that there is only one automorphism of $\mathbb{R}$ --- I am more curious to see if the reasoning above is correct.

Comment: “Must fix the elements of any subfield” seems a bit unclear to me. For example, $F$ is a subfield of itself. Obviously it doesn’t have to be the case that any automorphism of $F$ must fix all elements of $F$.

Comment: If automorphism isn't constant it hasn't to fix elements, but as isomorphism transforming subfield into itself satisfies needed property straight from this,definition

Comment: On the contrary, under a wide variety of hypotheses, an isomorphism from a field $F$ to a different field $E$ can often be extended to an automorphism of a field $K$ containing both $F$ and $E$.

Comment: An automorphism of a field $F$ always fixes the prime field. For characteristic $0$, that's the copy of $\mathbb{Q}$ contained in $F$. For characteristic $p\gt 0$, that's the copy of $\mathbb{F}_p$. Is that what you are trying to ask?

Comment: hmmmm. I'm really confused what is unclear. An automorphism is an isomorphism from a field to itself. assuming there is more than 1 automorphism on some field F(ie not just the identity automorphism), must it be the case that (this non-identity automorphism) maps all of the elements of a proper subfield (G) to themselves? (while all of the other elements (ie elements in F\G) are mapped somewhere else).

Comment: No, in general not every automorphism maps every subfield to itself. Why would it?

Comment: I read some proof that used that reasoning, and I didn't buy it

Comment: You had some answers now, ness – what is the problem? what more do you need? better yet, why don't you work out an example?

Comment: If you'd like an explicit example, consider the map $a + b \sqrt 2 \mapsto a - b \sqrt 2$ on $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2)$. Or even stronger, the subfield of $\Bbb C$ generated by the three complex cube roots of $2$ has an automorphism that moves $\sqrt[3] 2$ and hence moves the proper subfield $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3] 2)$. Or alternatively, if $K$ is any field, the field of rational functions $K(x, y)$ has an automorphism swapping $x$ and $y$.  I think something may have been lost in translation between the proof you read and what you've told us here. If you'd still like an answer, could you show us the proof?